# (Where) Can I ask questions regarding pointers to websites?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I want to know certain sites discussing interview questions/tests (preferably country/company-wise).

Should I post the questions on StackOverflow, Meta, or Programmers...?
... or elsewhere?

eg.
"Tell me websites like 'FreshersWorld.com' that cater to experienced professionals interview questions and scenario (company test-papers)"

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example question?

Comment: answering on question in question, there is glassdoor and careercup (not advertising)

Comment: Given that example question, I can't think of a SE site that would accept it.  It'd strike me as "likely [to] solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" and thus be "Not Constructive."

Comment: How about a chat room?

Comment: Charles, certainly these sites won't then be helpful/useful (to me) though
Omnomnom, what about allinterview.com and geekinterview.com?

Comment: See [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @gnat, it says 'not about---websites like these---

Answer (score 11):

That type of question won't fit well anywhere; it's a list/poll-type question.

You'd get a collection links to everyone's favorite source, at best with a short explanation of why they think it's good/useful, and possibly collecting some borderline spam posts along the way. Not constructive would be the close reason I'd use — the answers can't be objectively rated against each other, and they'll link-rot like all other links (but these are not salvageable).

You might try in a general chat room though, or a more specific room if you're more interested in certain languages/areas.

Comment: It can just be a question...
...I need directions!

Comment: Search engines are great to get directions. Forums & discussion boards too.